# How do I retain part of string and part of string send to masking in informatica

Tags: informatica

I have string variable `20722222222` I want to retain `207` and rest of the values I want to send it for masking.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think we need more info. You can SUBSTR(COL,1,3) to separate 207 and rest. But main issue is masking. What you mean by 'send to masking'? There can be many logic for masking and its different for different org. Tell us more on this please.

Comment: Hello , I have a mapplet which masks the 10 digit number which is 22222222 but I don’t want to mask 207 number I want to retain that value and only mask 22222222.

Comment: please use SUBSTR(DATA_COLUMN,3) --> this will give you  22222222. Pass it into mapplet. Basically this will give you string after 3rd character. If this field is a number then you can use TO_INTEGER(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(DATA_COLUMN),3))